# Error property not readable on type Error- on a DataTable with Edit and selection option

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I was trying to implement a data table with edit and selection feature. 
This is my XHTML part

```
 <p:dataTable var="selectedRow" value="#{editBean.subStudyPlanList}" id="display" editable="true"
            selectionMode="single" selection="#{editBean.selectedSubStudyPlan}" 
            paginator="true" rows="10" >
```

The error I got is this.

```
selection="#{editBean.selectedSubStudyPlan}": Property 'selectedSubStudyPlan' not readable on typecom.buddhiedge.server.entity.StudyplanCategory
```

I was using the below method to do the same.

Implementing `SelectableDataModel` interface and extending a `DataModel` like `ListDataModel` for filling the `dataTable`.

Please Help to solve this issue.

Answer (score 9):

> selection="#{editBean.selectedSubStudyPlan}": Property 'selectedSubStudyPlan' not readable on type com.buddhiedge.server.entity.StudyplanCategory

This exception means that the `#{editBean.selectedSubStudyPlan}` property doesn't have a public getter method. In other words, there is no public `getSelectedSubStudyPlan()` method on the `StudyplanCategory` class.

Write/autogenerate one and this problem should disappear.

Comment: Hi But selectedSubStudyPlan is a field in the editBean(ManagedBean).There is no field called selectedSubStudyPlan in the entity class StudyPlanCategorey.Please Help.